# Clean down the index before each text (Mocha, Elastic)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, elasticsearch, mocha.js

How do we clear down the index before each test? (at the moment it fails my test, with a timeout)

I have tried

- DeleteBy (I have tried the term and q)
- http delete
- delete the index

I have the following code:

```
var assert = require("assert"),
    elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch'),
    request = require('request'),
    q = require('q'),
    client;

client = new elasticsearch.Client();

describe('people', function(){

    beforeEach(function(done){

        //is this correct?
        //looks like poeple get deleted.
        client.deleteByQuery({
            index: 'people',
            q: '*'
        }, function (error, response) {
            done();
        });

        //I have also tried the following:

        //this way returns an accept code.

//       var deleteOptions = {
//           method: 'DELETE',
//           uri: 'http://localhost:9200/people/person'
//       };
//
//       webApi(deleteOptions).then(function(data){
//           //{"acknowledged":true}
//           console.log(data.body);
//           done();
//       });


        //the following throws an exception

        //delete index

//       client.indices.delete('people').then(function(del){
//           console.log(del);
//           client.indices.create('people').then(function(ct){
//               console.log(ct);
//               done();
//           });
//       });






    });

    describe('add a entry into the index', function(){
        it('should add Dave as a person to the database', function(done){

            //THIS TEST WILL FAIL
            //Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

            //I have tried adding a timeout.

            assert.equal(1,1);
        });
    });
});

var webApi = function(options){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var handle = function (error, response, body) {
        //console.log(body);
        if(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve({response:response, body:body});
        }
    };
    request(options, handle);
    return deferred.promise; //NOTE: we now return a promise
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test that you marked with `THIS TEST WILL FAIL` fails with a timeout because you never call `done()` in it. You've declared the anonymous function you pass to `it` with a parameter, which tells Mocha that your test is asynchronous (even if the code in it is not asynchronous right now) and thus Mocha waits for `done()` to be called. You can either call it, or remove the parameter from your function.